# BlockNotify/WalletNotify - but without the console window

Tags: bitcoind, server

I use the *walletnotify* and *blocknotify* config options on bitcoind to have the server call two executables on new transactions/blocks. This all works fine. The two executables (Windows executables) are both designed to run without a console window, and they do.

That is, they do when I run them. When bitcoind runs them, I get a brief flash of a console window. As I run these on my development machine while developing, it's driving me to distraction. Does anyone have any idea to prevent this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took me some, but I think I have an answer. I went trough the source code and found the `runCommand()` function that actually starts the command provided by notify options (it is called mostly from `main.cpp` and the code runs in a separate thread).

From `util.cpp`

```
void runCommand(std::string strCommand)
{
    int nErr = ::system(strCommand.c_str());
    if (nErr)
        LogPrintf("runCommand error: system(%s) returned %d\n", strCommand, nErr);
}
```

It uses the standard C library method `system()`, which is probably giving you the flashing window. Normally one would use [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or similar) to prevent the flash effect and have much more control over the spawned process (I don't know why the developers chose `system()` here, but I guess it was just easier). I believe the behavior of the `system()` call is system dependent.

Also, when you say `bitcoind`, you mean the CLI interface of bitcoin, right? Is there a `bitcoind` console window running? As for a solution, you could edit the source code to use `CreateProcess()` with the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag, that would do the trick.

Comment: I've not yet moved to using 0.9's new bitcoin-cli executable, so I just run bitcoind and talk to it over RPC. So yes, there is a bitcoind console window running. I don't really want to patch the code, so I guess I will just have to live with it. If it annoys me enough I will stick it in a VM :) Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the conditions are for spawning a new shell, but I have seen this being different before on different machines. I for example don't get these flashes, no idea why. I could patch the code for you, but you'd have to recompile yourself (then we know for sure haha). You are welcome.